Weird info ordering in scikit-learn trees
When plotting scikit-learn trees (on iris data as an example), as in the below code:
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree
iris = load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X, y)
tree.plot_tree(clf)


every node of the resulting tree (but leaves) reports BEFORE the split criterion (feature and cutoff value) and THEN the pre-split information (gini, samples, and value). I feel this quite counter-intuitive, indeed. And there seems to be no way of inverting info. Shouldn't the pre-split info be reported in every tree node before the split criterion?

I see your point.
The scikit-learn design emphasizes a “forward-looking” view, focusing on the decision process.
This means that the focus is on which feature is being split on and at what threshold.
This design likely aligns with the idea that once a node is created, the split criterion immediately defines the future structure of the tree.
No way to change this behavior in sklearn.
